# How to change default IP route proirity for specific network interface

Tags: linux, fedora, network-interface, route

I am using couple interfaces on my board. 
eth2 is my control interface - I want to control board through ssh on this interface.
eth1 is my back-2-back interface with another board I have.

My problem occurs after reboot. Defult ip route is first set for eth1, then for eht2.
This forces me to ssh through eth1 (back-2-back), as all of replies to my ssh traffic going to eth2, will be ip forwarded and push out of eht1.

How can I configure interface's boot order so that eth2 is first to register default ip route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the new defaut gatway , Remove the old one then save routing information to a configuration file:

```
route add default via xx.xx.xx.xx
route del default via yy.yy.yy.yy
ip route add default gw xx.xx.xx.xx
ip route del default gw yy.yy.yy.yy
```

The new gatway = `xx.xx.xx.xx`

the old gatway = `yy.yy.yy.yy`

Save routing information:

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

add the following line:

```
gateway xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Restart networking:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: thanks, in the end I discovered that I had GATEWAY field in my 'ifcfg-eth1' and that was causing linux to add that defualt rule to routing table.